# In Twisted what's the difference between processExited and processEnded?

Tags: twisted

As the title says, what's the difference between those two functions on ProcessProtocol classes? Documentation is a bit sparse on when should one be used instead of another?

Preferably, I'm looking for some examples of use cases that demonstrate that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I guess the documentation is somewhat sparse on this point.  If no such ticket exists, please feel free to [file a ticket](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/newticket) to improve the API docs.

`processExited` is invoked when a process has *exited* in the formal process-management sense, i.e. called `exit()` or returned from `main()`.

However, this is not always what you want.  Sometimes a process spawns a subprocess, hands off its stdin and stdout, delegates responsibility for producing the data that you (the spawning parent process, in this case) wants, and then `exit()`s because it's done setting things up.

`processEnded` is invoked when a process has both exited *and* finished doing all the I/O on its managed file descriptors (`stdin`, `stdout`, and `childFDs`) and they've been closed.  If you're spawning something just to read its output, this is the notification you most likely care about.